# A relation between $Spec((1+I)^{-1}R)$ and $Spec(R/J)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, prime-ideals, zariski-topology

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and let $I$ and $J$ be two finitely generated ideals of $R$. Clearly $1+I:=\{1+i:i\in I\}$ is a multiplicative closed  subset of $R$. We can consider the following natural homeomorphisms $Spec((1+I)^{-1}R)\cong\{p\in Spec(R): 1+i\not\in p\}$ and $Spec(R/J)\cong\{p\in Spec(R): J\subseteq p\}$.

> I am looking for (necessary or(and) sufficient)conditions on $I$ and $J$ under which $$\{p\in Spec(R): 1+i\not\in p\}\subseteq \{p\in Spec(R): J\subseteq p\}.$$
>   Or under the above homeomorphisms 
>   $$Spec((1+I)^{-1}R) \subseteq Spec(R/J).$$

Note that $Spec(S)$ is the set of all prime ideals of a ring $S$.